# How to create an if statement for onclick on a attribute

Tags: php, html, if-statement

I want to make an if statement that if they click a link with "Embed" link type, an onclick event will occur. This is my code, but it doesn't work.

I Have two link types:

1. External //This link will open in new tab
2. Embed    // This is my problem, i want the embed link(video) to load in my page not open in new page or new tab that is why i need the onclick to work if they click this link type.

```
<a target="_blank' href="<?php get_option('url') ?>/wpwm-redirect?link_id=<?php $t_link->linkID ?>" <?php if($t_link->link_type == 'Embed') echo ' onclick="ayeLoadVideo('/wpwm-redirect?link_id=<?php $t_link->linkID ?>'); return false;"'; ?>> <?php $t_link->link_title ?> </a>
```

Comment: Please fix your code formatting.

Comment: My friend made it work, but he doesn't want to share the code.

Comment: Tnx :) i already fixed it

Comment: You can't use `<?` inside `echo`. Use string concatenation.

Comment: Please edit my code? i'm new to php, i didn't create this code, i edited it from the plugin i bought.

Comment: added correct php tag for echo

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change:

```
echo ' onclick="ayeLoadVideo('/wpwm-redirect?link_id=<?=$t_link->linkID ?>'); return false;"'
```

to:

```
echo ' onclick="ayeLoadVideo(\'/wpwm-redirect?link_id=' . $t_link->linkID . '\'); return false;"'
```

1. You need to escape the quotes that are inside the string, otherwise they'll end the string.
2. You can't use `<?=` inside a string. `<?` is used for switching from HTML code into PHP code, but you're already in PHP code when you execute `echo`. Use string concatenation in PHP code.